# Send a string message to multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-3.x

I have an IRC client that receives messages on a socket.

From this client I have created several bots that connect to other peoples chat channels on twitch. (These are authorized and not Spam bots!).

Each bot is created in a separate thread that takes the channel name along with a few other parameters.

My issue is my IRC socket can only bind to one port and this handles all the IRC messages, each message has a #channel string as the third word-string that directs it to a particular channel. These messages can be handled inside each bot as each one knows the name of its channel.

My problem is; How do I send the string received over the socket to multiple threads?

```
import time
import socket
import threading
import string
import sys
import os

class IRCBetBot:
    #irc ref
    irc = None

    def __init__(self,IRCRef,playerName,channelName,currencyName):

        #assign variables
        self.irc = IRCRef
        self.channel = '#' + channelName

        self.irc.send(('JOIN ' + self.channel + '\r\n') .encode("utf8"))

        #create readbuffer to hold strings from IRC
        readbuffer = ""

        # This is the main loop
        while 1:

            ##readbuffer## <- need to send message from IRC to this variable 

            for line in temp:
                line=str.rstrip(line)
                line=str.split(line)

                if (len(line) >= 4) and ("PRIVMSG" == line[1]) and (self.channel == line[2]) and not ("jtv" in line[0]):
                    #call function to handle user message
                if(line[0]=="PING"):
                    self.irc.send(("PONG %s\r\n" % line[0]).encode("utf8"))




def runAsThread(ircref,userName, channelName, currencyPrefix):
    print("Got to runAsThread with : " + str(userName) + " " + str(channelName) + " " + str(currencyPrefix))
    IRCBetBot(ircref,userName,channelName,currencyPrefix)

# Here we create the IRC connection
#IRC connection variables
nick = 'mybot'                  #alter this value with the username used to connect to IRC eg: "username".
password = "oauth:mykey"        #alter this value with the password used to connect to IRC from the username above.
server = 'irc.twitch.tv'
port = 6667

#create IRC socket
irc = socket.socket()

irc.connect((server, port))

#sends variables for connection to twitch chat
irc.send(('PASS ' + password + '\r\n').encode("utf8"))
irc.send(('USER ' + nick + '\r\n').encode("utf8"))
irc.send(('NICK ' + nick + '\r\n').encode("utf8"))

# Array to hold all the new threads 
threads = [] 
# authorised Channels loaded from file in real program
authorisedChannels = [["user1","#channel1","coin1"],["user2","#channel2","coin2"],["user3","#channel3","coin3"]]

for item in authorisedChannels:
    try:
        userName = item[0]
        channelName = item[1]
        currencyPrefix = item [2]
        myTuple = (irc,userName,channelName,currencyPrefix)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=runAsThread,args = myTuple,)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
        time.sleep(5) # wait to avoid too many connections to IRC at once from same IP
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred while creating threads.")
        print(str(e))

#create readbuffer to hold strings from IRC
readbuffer = ""

# This is the main loop
while 1:
    readbuffer= readbuffer+self.irc.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    temp=str.split(readbuffer, "\n")
    readbuffer=temp.pop( )
    #
    #Need to send readbuffer to each IRCBetBot() created in runAsThread that contains a while 1: loop to listen for strings in its __init__() method.
    #   

print ("Waiting...")

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print ("Complete.")
```

I need to somehow get the readbuffer from the main loop into each IRCBetBot object created in separate threads? Any ideas?

Comment: are you trying to send readbuffer to every thread, or just whichever thread the message is actually for?

Comment: Well either works, I only really need to send the message to the appropriate thread, but the fitering can either be done before hand or in the thread. I thought doing it in the thread might be better because it knows who it is ie it's channel name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that shows how you can do this using a queue for each thread. Instead of just creating a list of threads, we create a dict of threads with the channel as the key, and store both the thread object and a queue that can be used to talk to the thread in the dict.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import threading
from queue import Queue


class IRCBetBot(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, q, playerName, channelName, currencyName):
        super().__init__()
        self.channel = channelName
        self.playerName = playerName
        self.currencyName = currencyName
        self.queue = q 

    def run(self):
        readbuffer = ""
        while 1:
            readbuffer = self.queue.get()  # This will block until a message is sent to the queue.
            print("{} got msg {}".format(self.channel, readbuffer))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    authorisedChannels = [["user1","#channel1","coin1"],
                          ["user2","#channel2","coin2"],
                          ["user3","#channel3","coin3"]]

threads = {}
for item in authorisedChannels:
    try:
        userName = item[0]
        channelName = item[1]
        currencyPrefix = item [2]
        myTuple = (userName,channelName,currencyPrefix)
        q = Queue() 
        thread = IRCBetBot(q, *myTuple )
        thread.start()
        threads[channelName] = (q, thread)
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred while creating threads.")
        print(str(e))

while 1:
    a = input("Input your message (channel: msg): ")
    channel, msg = a.split(":")
    threads[channel][0].put(msg)  # Sends a message using the queue object
```

As you can see, when messages come into the socket, we parse the channel out (which your code already does) and then just pass the message on to the appropriate queue in our thread dict.

Sample output (slightly tweaked so the output isn't scrambled due to the concurrent `print` calls):

```
dan@dantop:~$ ./test.py 
Input your message (channel: msg): #channel1: hi there
#channel1 got msg  hi there
Input your message (channel: msg): #channel2: another one
#channel2 got msg  another one
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go I'm working hard on incorporating it into my code. Is there a reason you removed the IRCRef reference from the IRCBetBot constructor? I have got the messages sending as written but occasionally the IRCBetBot sends a message back to the wrong channel, I reincorporated the IRCRef into the IRCBetBot, is this the reason?

Comment: @Zac, I just removed `IRCRef` because it wasn't necessary to demonstrate how to pass the messages between threads. I'm not sure what the cause of the issue you're seeing is...When `IRCRef` sends a message, does it explicitly say what channel it should go to?

Comment: This works fine now, how would I send a message to all channels at once? I tried putting threads in a: for loop: "for item in threads" but I can't work out how to index the queue from there and item[0].put() just returns the error : string has no put method.

Comment: @Zac When you iterate over a dict like that, it just returns the keys, not the values. So you'd do it like this: `for channel in threads: threads[channel].put()`

Comment: I know I should avoid thanks, but thanks: the code I used to do the above was "for k, v in threads.items():   v[0].put(line)"

Answer (score 0):

Well one way to do it would be to have an array of readBuffers similar to the array of threads. And then each thread basically is waiting on data on it's particular readbuffer.

When you get in data you can pass it to the thread you're interested in or just copy the data over to all the readbuffers and let the threads process it if they are interested. An observer pattern would work best in this case.

Comment: How would I determine which readbuffer is read by which thread? Do you suggest using the threads[] and readbuffers[] and keeping each index the same ie: treads[0] <-> readbuffers[0]. If so how do I access/read readbuffer[x] from within my thread?

Comment: Yes the 1-1 index based mapping would work. If the readBuffers is a global variable similar to threads then you can access readBuffers from the thread no problem :)